# dmidecode - what is the "system"?

Tags: linux, bios, dmidecode

In `dmidecode` types

```
0   BIOS Information
1   System Information
2   Baseboard (or Module) Information
```

What is the second entry? For exmaple, First is for bios, second for Motherboard. What does `System` here mean? CPU?

The man page says:

> dmidecode  is  a  tool  for  dumping  a  computer's DMI (some say
>          SMBIOS) table contents in a  human-readable  format.  This  table
>          contains  a  description  of the system's hardware components, as
>          well as other useful pieces of information such as serial numbers
>          and  BIOS  revision.  Thanks to this table, you can retrieve this
>          information without having to  probe  for  the  actual  hardware.
>          While this is a good point in terms of report speed and safeness,
>          this also makes the presented information possibly unreliable.

dmidecode -t system' didn't help either:

```
[root@localhost ~]# dmidecode -t system

\# dmidecode 2.12
SMBIOS 2.4 present.

Handle 0x0001, DMI type 1, 27 bytes
System Information
    Manufacturer:                                  
    Product Name:                                  
    Version:                                  
    Serial Number:                                  
    UUID: 89CFC20E-41D1-11DF-8DA9-001CC0C1735C
    Wake-up Type: Power Switch
    SKU Number: Not Specified
    Family: Not Specified

Handle 0x0028, DMI type 12, 5 bytes
System Configuration Options
    Option 1: To Be Filled By O.E.M.

Handle 0x0030, DMI type 32, 20 bytes
System Boot Information
    Status: No errors detected
```

Comment: It's your machine (your computer if you want...)... the overall system information (see detailed [DMTF spec](http://www.dmtf.org/sites/default/files/standards/documents/DSP0134V2.4Final.pdf), page 36: System Information (Type 1))

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Probably the best place to look it up!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`system` refers to the entire box.

If you buy a pre-assembled computer with a specific model name, the vendor would put that information into the `system` block. If you buy components and assemble them yourself, that information remains empty.

Comment: Thanks! Should I assume that the `System` section is some BIOS (mine is Gigabyte Dual Bios version F15), also refers to the same? It seems like this might not necessarily be the case (at least on my Computer), as my "system" is perhaps an assembled one but the System model name says `B75M-D3H` which is a motherboard model number.

Comment: Quite often, manufacturers are lazy and neglect to update the information. Depending on the motherboard vendor, these fields come empty, as copies of the motherboard info or with nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

system is your machine, You have samething in some command as `system class`
Check it:

```
hwinfo --sys |less
```

Comment: What do you mean by `machine`? what is `system class`? I have a fresh fedora 20 installation, and it doesn't have `hwinfo` command on it.

Comment: `yum install hwinfo`

Comment: I still don't understand what `system` or machine refers to here. Is it the `CPU`, `motherboard` or something else?